# stop cypher query when condition failed

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph model, and I want to query based on some conditions..

I used `With` and `Where` to make the nested query; it would be like

```
START n1=node:ValueIndex('VALUE:DCM') 
MATCH p1 = n1-[r1:REL]->n2
WHERE some_condition [1]

With n1,n2,r1,p1
match p2 = n1-[r1:REL]->n2-[r2:PASS_REL]->n3
where  some_condition [2]


With n1,n2,r1,p1, n3,r2, p2
match p3 = n1-[r1:REL]->n2-[r2:REL]->n3-[r3:REL]->n4
where some_condition [3]

With All the values above
Where "condition that must be applied to all nodes" [4]

RETURN n1 ,n2,n3, n4
```

in this case, the conditions 1,2,3 4 must be true to get the right data..

But what I really want, is that when any of the conditions is false, the query stops but the data from the previous conditions must be returned..

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: For queries like this, I'd recommend doing it programmatically using the Java lib or similar to do the logic checks before returning the results.

Comment: But how can it be done in java ?? I think it would take too long to check for this, as I may have more than 10 condition..

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit too complex to do in a good fashion with Cypher. I would look into a Server Extension or Plugin using the full power of Java (or other JVM scripting language), see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-extending.html